# Creating scripts for run project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can simple nodejs server.

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   ...
}

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Express app listening on port:${PORT}`);
});
```

And my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-middleware",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "files": [
    "bin/*"
  ],
  "main": "./bin/scripts.js",
  "bin": {
    "scripts": "./bin/scripts.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/scripts.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
  },
}
```

I create script for run my project.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { program } = require('commander');

program.version('0.0.1');
program
    .command('start')
    .description('Start project in development environment')
    .action(() => {
        console.log('Script starting...');

        exec('node ./src/server.js', (err, stdout, stderr) => console.log(stdout));
    });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

After I want to show label

```
Express app listening on port:3000
```

How I can have on next process? I want to add other command before run project like this copy files and etc.

Comment: Your last sentence is really hard to understand, please make it clearer.

Comment: Do you want to add another command? You can do it by adding another `program.command('doSomethingElse')`

Comment: `"copy-files": "node ./bin/scripts.js copy-files"`, then add copy-files command to your script, kind of obvious

Answer (score 0):

The requirement isn't entirely clear: but a simple option might be to include the file copy command in the "start" script in `package.json`, something like this:

```js
\\package.json
"scripts": {
  "start": "cp ./somefile.txt ./to/somewhere && node ./src/server.js"
},
```

...or else...

```js
\\package.json
"scripts": {
  "copy": "cp ./somefile.txt ./to/somewhere"
  ,"start": "npm run copy && node ./src/server.js"
},
```